# Sort 80,412 files into folders based on name begins with

Tags: macos, finder, filesystem, folders, sort

Situation:

- a folder with 80,412 files
- all files named with CamelCase, some have a dash (-) separating the first word
- files can be grouped by beginning with the same word or letters(i.e. "ClientslistRebecca..." and "Clientslist-Adam...")
- no file name begins with a number
- very few files begin with a unique word

I need to take the first word, find all files that begin with that word, and create a folder named with that word. Repeat for all files.

The main complication is that sometimes a name begins with multiple capitals, followed by a word that also begins with a capital (i.e. "AWDRebecca..."). Not sure how to resolve that, but I'm fine with doing some manual cleanup afterwards if I get folders with "AWDRebecca", "AWDReports", "AWDNovember", but having a folder "A" will make it harder.

Comment: This probably requires a scripting solution. What have you tried so far?

Comment: Also, I assue that files starting with "AWDRebecca", "AWDReports", "AWDNovember" should end up in a folder called "AWD", right?

Comment: I just started on this task around, I use Automator workflows with Run Shell Script for most automatization.

Comment: And yes, AWD would be preferred folder name, with all AWD...'s inside.

Comment: We are not a script writing service, so if you have some steps of this already, please add them to the question.

Comment: I understand that, working on the script now, but I was also open to suggestions if there's an app, or a different script executor to do this. I'll update the question as soon as I have something.

Comment: I would just use shell scripts rather than automator calling shell scripts. ALso hard code the odd cases like AWD and move those first

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different. I'm wondering what the "the first word" for "ClientslistRebecca..." is... Is it "Clientlist" or "Client"? More generally, could you explain the rules how the first word is determined (for example, what is the rule for file names that contain both camel case and dashes)?

Comment: jaume, the folder is a collection of report, receipts, portfolios, project summaries, etc. Since it's a CamelCase words are separated by Capitals, sometimes a person naming the files used CamelCase with dashes. So in "ClientslistRebecca" and "Clientslist-Adam" the first word is "Clientslist". For "AWDRebecca" first word is "AWD" (name of one of our clients, that Rebecca works with.

Answer (score 1):

A shell snippet like

```
for i in *; do
  case "$i" in
    [A-Z][A-Z]*) # $i has several leading caps
        dir=$(sed -E -e 's|([A-Z]+)[A-Z].*|\1|' <<< "$i")
        echo mkdir -p "$dir"
        echo mv "$i" "$dir"/
        ;;
    [A-Z][a-z]*) # $i has one leading cap
        dir=$(sed -E -e 's|([A-Z][a-z]+).*|\1|' <<< "$i")
        echo mkdir -p "$dir"
        echo mv "$i" "$dir"/
        ;;
    *) echo "Huh: $i"
       ;;
  esac
done
```

should work. As written it will just print the commands on the screen. If they look sensible, remove the four `echo` before `mkdir`/`mv`.

Also, for 80'000 files, the `for i in *` part may fail. If this is the case, run it in batches with `for i in [A-E]*`, `for i in [F-K]*` etc.

PS: It will fail for files with a ALLCAPS name. If you have does, please comment so I can add another rule.